# NativeScript/TypeScript : cannot find namespace 'android'

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I have the following code in my typescript file

```
  const startActivity: android.app.Activity = app.android.startActivity;
  const context: android.content.Context = app.android.context;
  let intent: android.content.Intent;
```

why does it shows an error 'cannot find namespace 'android'. Do i need to install plugin related to native android (eg tns-platform-declarations)

Thanks.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you're correct. Use the `tns-platform-declarations` and follow the setup it provides so that TypeScript is aware of the native android/ios APIs.

After installing, the main thing is to create a `references.d.ts` file in the root of your project with the following:

`/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android.d.ts" />`

Also be sure to pay attention to this from the docs:

> d.ts files require a lot of memory and CPU. Consider adding skipLibCheck option to tsconfig file.